# Perl substr(STRING, @ARRAY) ne substr(STRING, OFFSET, LENGTH)?

Tags: perl, substr

Why is this in Perl:

```
@x=(0,2); 
substr('abcd',@x)
```

evaluated as "cd"?

And this:

```
substr('abcd',0,2);
```

evaluated as "ab"?

Answer (score 12):

The documented syntax of the [`substr`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr.html) operator is

```
substr EXPR,OFFSET,LENGTH,REPLACEMENT
substr EXPR,OFFSET,LENGTH
substr EXPR,OFFSET
```

not

```
substr EXPR,ARRAY
```

or the more generic

```
substr EXPR,LIST
```

This is reflected in the output of [`prototype`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/prototype.html) (although you can't always rely on this).

```
$ perl -E'say prototype "CORE::substr"'
$$;$$
```

- `substr`'s 1st argument is evaluated in scalar context.
- `substr`'s 2nd argument is evaluated in scalar context.
- `substr`'s 3rd argument (optional) is evaluated in scalar context.
- `substr`'s 4th argument (optional) is evaluated in scalar context.

`@x` in scalar context is the number of elements it contains (`2` in this case).

You can achieve what you want using the following:

```
sub mysubstr {
    if    (@_ == 2) { substr($_[0], $_[1]) }
    elsif (@_ == 3) { substr($_[0], $_[1], $_[2]) }
    elsif (@_ == 4) { substr($_[0], $_[1], $_[2], $_[3]) }
    else { die }
}

my @x = (0, 2);
mysubstr('abcd',@x)
```

Comment: Thanks for the lighting fast answers

Answer (score 5):

substr has a prototype as a built in function, so @x is not expanded is evaluated in a scalar context, which returns 2, so basically you are calling substr('abcd',scalar(@x))

Answer (score 4):

The first uses `@x` in scalar context ... meaning the size of `@x` so `substr('abcd',2)` gives `cd`.